# TabLayout without AppCompat?

Tags: android, layout, tabs, android-appcompat

I've got a (working) Android App. I don't care about older versions of Android OS; the app is aimed strictly at the latest versions only.

Recently I decided to add a TabLayout to the App's UI. I was following

https://android.jlelse.eu/tablayout-and-viewpager-in-your-android-app-738b8840c38a

Now I got it working, but one problem is that the tutorial above assumes you're going to extend your Activity from

```
android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
```

(rather than the simple android.app.Activity) and keeps using various 'AppCompat' things, like

```
android.support.v4.app.Fragment
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager
android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter
```

Now, what is even worse, this forces me to use an 'AppCompat' theme (I've tried a few default ones and all of them look like s**t)

```
setTheme(R.style.Theme_AppCompat_Light_NoActionBar);
```

I'd like to add a TabLayout to my app while keeping its Activity extended from android.app.Activity. Is that possible?

Comment: The `Fragment` classes shouldn't really be an issue. Just use the platform `Fragment` stuff. As for the `TabLayout` and theme, I would think you should be able to do that if you handle its instantiation yourself; e.g., add it to your layout programmatically. For example, if you do something like `TabLayout tabs = new TabLayout(new ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.Theme_AppCompat_Whichever));`, then you won't have to set an AppCompat theme on the whole `Activity`.

Comment: but what should I be using in place of android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter ? There seems to be no 'android.app.FragmentPagerAdapter' ...

Comment: The v13 `FragmentPagerAdapter` handles platform `Fragments`: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v13/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.

Comment: Yep, just ran a quick test, and it all works.

Comment: Couldn't I simply do it with a TabLayout alone, without the ViewPager? What is this ViewPager there for anyway?

Comment: Sure. `TabLayout` is not inherently tied to `ViewPager`. It's basically just a glorified `RadioGroup`.

Comment: Ok, thanks Mike. It's all working now :)